# Photos taken with native iOS Camera app are always UIImageOrientationUp

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uiimageorientation

I’m working on building a test case of all possible image and video orientations taken with the iPhone.

I’ve used the native iOS camera app to shoot all 8 possible orientations (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) yet for the sample code I’m running it all seems to reporting that the images are

Reference code is `printOrientationForName(@“UIImage”, image.imageOrientation);`
Working example can be found here [sugarso/Orientation](https://github.com/sugarso/Orientation/blob/stackoverflow_q/Orientation/SOSViewController.m#L45)

Output is here

```
2014-05-04 15:42:39.651 Orientation[10293:60b] ASSET ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=E819189D-0696-4C94-8046-804CBF1551E8&ext=JPG
2014-05-04 15:42:39.661 Orientation[10293:60b] UIImage UIImageOrientationUp [0]
2014-05-04 15:42:39.663 Orientation[10293:60b] ASSET ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=19E29D06-96F2-4B35-A0EB-B2A809A02C79&ext=JPG
2014-05-04 15:42:39.665 Orientation[10293:60b] UIImage UIImageOrientationUp [0]
2014-05-04 15:42:39.667 Orientation[10293:60b] ASSET ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=265261C0-0479-41C4-BFDC-91AD6887A81F&ext=JPG
2014-05-04 15:42:39.668 Orientation[10293:60b] UIImage UIImageOrientationUp [0]
2014-05-04 15:42:39.669 Orientation[10293:60b] ASSET ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=BE459DAE-0CFD-4D93-8050-5C62D9F5D0F9&ext=JPG
2014-05-04 15:42:39.670 Orientation[10293:60b] UIImage UIImageOrientationUp [0]
```

As you can see, all the images are created with UIImageOrientationUp. I’m examining the wrong property? Or is the camera app flips all the photos? How should I be taking photos with the given layout.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on different things, for instance:

- if you do not save them on the asset library along with their metadata and later you open them, they will load with the default orientation (UIImageOrintationUp)
- if you save them as png, images don't have a knowledge about their orientation
- the orientation is different if you load/shoot them with the picker, or delegate buffer, or still images

I wrote this post on my blog ([Exif pain](http://cloudintouch.it/2014/04/03/exif-pain-orientation-ios/)), maybe it will help to check your issue

Comment: Hello Andrea, I’m saving the images with the iOS camera app. I’m only analyzing them with custom code. The iPhone camera saves images as jpeg. Does it not also add Exif data for orientation? Because should you capture a video prefferedTransform does contain the required orientation rotation data.

Comment: It does, but you should also load image metadata along with them http://biasedbit.com/alasset-image-orientation/

Comment: Even though your answer did not give a direct solution to my issue but it did point in the right direction!!!